# How to dynamically load a PHP page inside another PHP page's <DIV>?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I currently have two PHP pages: test1.php and test2.php. Inside test1 are 2 DIVs: one named "SubmitDiv", and one named "DisplayDiv". Inside SubmitDiv is a Submit button. When the user clicks on the Submit button, it should load test2.php inside DisplayDiv. Currently test2.php will only display "Hello World". I want it to load test2.php inside the DisplayDiv so that the test1.php page doesn't need to break stride or otherwise reload.

And this is where I am stuck. I am aware that I likely have to make use of AJAX in order for it to dynamically load the test2.php page inside DisplayDiv. How this is done, however, has bested me, and my attempts at it have so far failed. Using the below scripts, which I have pieced together from online searches of this issue, when I try to click on the Submit button - which should load test2.php inside DisplayDiv - instead it just refreshes the whole page and no test2.php is loaded.

test1.php:

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadSubmitResults() {
        $(function() {
            $('#DisplayDiv').load('test2.php');
        });
    }
</script>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <form id="SubmitForm" method="post">
            <div id="SubmitDiv" style="background-color:black;">
                <button type="submit" form="SubmitForm" onclick="loadSubmitResults();">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="DisplayDiv" style="background-color:red;">
            <!-- This is where test2.php should be inserted -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

test2.php:

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
    <div id="page" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <?php
            echo "Hello World.";
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove type="submit" from button tag, a normal submit refreshes the page

Comment: `$(function() {})` isn't needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this were something I was working on, I'd change:

```
               <button type="submit" form="QueryForm" onclick="loadQueryResults();">Submit Query</button>
```

to

```
               <button type="submit" form="QueryForm" onclick="return loadQueryResults();">Submit Query</button>
```

Then I'd change your loadQueryResults function to:

```
function loadQueryResults() {
    $('#DisplayDiv').load('test2.php');
    return false;
}
```

What this is doing is then returning the value of false to the onclick of the button which as a type of "submit" will, by default, submit the form.  Returning any false value on a form submit will cause the form to not submit.  Returning false is a general rule when trying to prevent default events from running.

Comment: Thanks. Adding the "return false" to the function and a "return " to the onclick= event seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The structure here is a little strange:

```
function loadQueryResults() {
    $(function() {
        $('#DisplayDiv').load('test2.php');
    });
}
```

You're declaring a function, but inside of that function you call the jQuery function and pass it a function with the code you want to run?  Normally the latter is for running something when the document is ready.  It shouldn't be needed here.  My guess is that this inner code (the one line you want to run) never actually gets executed.

Does a simpler version like this work for you?:

```
function loadQueryResults() {
    $('#DisplayDiv').load('test2.php');
}
```

This should just run the code you want when the function is called, without the various decorations of the jQuery function.

For good measure, you should also return `false` to try to prevent the default submit action:

```
function loadQueryResults() {
    $('#DisplayDiv').load('test2.php');
    return false;
}
```

You can further improve this by using a selector in the call to `.load()` to pick out only the parts of the DOM that you want.  Things like `html` and `body` might be stripped out automatically, but explicitly doing things is better than guessing:

```
$('#DisplayDiv').load('test2.php #page');
```

Of course, now you're also in a situation where you may end up with multiple elements of the id `page` in the same DOM, which is invalid.  You may want to consider changing some of your ids.

Comment: he has a submit button which refreshes page, that is the issue

Comment: The simpler version does the exact same thing as before: refresh with no changes made.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with the code below:

**test1.php:**

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called.
$('#SubmitForm').submit(function( event ) {

    $.ajax({
            url: 'test2.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: $('#SubmitForm').serialize(),
            success: function(content)
            {
                $("#DisplayDiv").html(content);
            }  
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});

});
</script>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <form id="SubmitForm" method="post">
            <div id="SubmitDiv" style="background-color:black;">
                <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="DisplayDiv" style="background-color:red;">
            <!-- This is where test2.php should be inserted -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

test2.php:

```
<div id="page" style="background-color:yellow;">
    <?php
        echo "Hello World.";
    ?>
</div>
```